# To have Supersized background slideshow image not cover the full screen?

Tags: jquery, css

There are many full screen background stretcher scripts out there. I'm using this http://buildinternet.com/2011/07/supersized-3-2-fullscreen-jquery-slideshow/

I'm trying to achieve an effect that instead of a background photo covering the full screen, it leaves 250px to the left of the screen(for a fixed sidebar), and the background fills the rest. It is important that the full width of the photo shown in the right portion of the screen.

This is the site I'm working on. As you can see, the background is pushed to right by sidebar width but part of background is cut off as a result.

http://princeseafoodrestaurant.com/dev/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which background image are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/faq.html#q-3), you can do this yourself:

> Does Supersized have to be fullscreen? Nope! You can define the
>   dimensions by adjusting the #supersized styles in the CSS file. You
>   will want to make all instances of position:fixed ->
>   position:absolute.

So, change this:

```
#supersized {  
    display:block; 
    position:fixed; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-999; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
}
```

to this:

```
#supersized {  
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
    left:250px; 
    right:0;
    top:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-999; 
    height:100%; 
}
```

Then change any other instances of `position:fixed` to `position:absolute`, and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks Norman. I've tried that before. But what this does is pushing the whole background to the right by 250px..so part of the background image will be pushed off the screen.

Comment: Did you remove the `width:100%` and include the `right:0` on `#supersized`, and set `position:absolute` on `#supersized li` though? I have seen this working in the demo (you may have to resize your screen before it works if you try it in firebug / developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when initiating the slideshow. Use these settings:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.supersized({              
        fit_always : 0,
        fit_portrait : 0,
        fit_landscape : 0,
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
#supersized {  
    display:block; 
    position:fixed; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-999; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```